# Number of combinations to draw the sum $n$ from set of $\{1,\dots,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How many different combinations $m$ are there to draw numbers $n_i$ with $n=\sum^{N}_i n_i$ from the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ without regarding order and without replacement, and for a given number of draws $N$.

I am studying [Euler's pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) and try to think about alternative ways to understand the multiplicities of the powers in the Euler function.

I have been drawing some diagrams for $n = 11$ and $N = 1, 2, 3, 4$ but while seeing some graphical patterns it seems very hard to derive numbers from these.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a closed form?

Comment: I do neither have any argument for that it should have nor for that it shouldn't have one, except Erd$\H$s caveat that there are lots of problems which are easy to state an impossible to solve.

Comment: For positive integers $n,N$ with $1 \le N \le n$, let $f(n,N)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into $N$ distinct positive integer parts. Using a Maple program, I computed the values of $f(n,N)$ for all pairs $(n,N)$ with $1 \le N \le n \le 100$. Looking at the data, I see no obvious pattern that would suggest a closed form.

Comment: Does OEIS give a hint? Thats what I would try now.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly a sequence, since $f$ is a function of two variables.

Comment: Yes, I'd search fix fixed N all separately. (Starting with 2)

Comment: It's obvious that
$$f(n,1)=1$$
for all positive integers $n$. Also, it's not hard to show that 
$$f(n,2) = \left\lfloor{{\small{\frac{n-1}{2}}}}\right\rfloor$$
for all positive integers $n$

Comment: What's your intended use of the values of $f$?

Comment: Well, its a brute force appraoch to the pentagonal number theorem (rather than Eulers guessing and using induction), that would work if $f(n,N)$ could be "deduced". What does OEIS give for $f(n,3)$

Comment: I'm fairly sure that if I tried, I could get an exact formula for $f(n,3)$ involving various floor expressions, but it would be an awkward formula, probably useless for your intended application. It's not an OEIS type sequence.

Comment: Its not contained? Thats great, you could submit it!

Comment: By its nature, it's not an appropriate sequence for OEIS. If you look at the data, you'll understand why.

Comment: Could you please send me the data for a few $N$?

Comment: Sure, but first let me check my data to see if it matches your equation.. .

Comment: I guess the (important!) leading zeros should be no obstacle.

Comment: Can you post that equation again?

Comment: $\sum_N \sum_n (-1)^n f(n,N) q^N$,  ($N->\infty$) should be the Euler function, I deleted because I haven't checked it. The inner sums must sum to either ${-1,0,1}$.

Comment: I don't see limits for those sums. Can you make it more precise?

Comment: Of course the limits of the sums are delicate as well. But when you fill the sequences with tailing zeros you can got to $\infty$.

Comment: I mean lower and upper limits for the indices. In other words, for the inner sum, $n$ goes from what to what, and in the outer sum, $N$ goes from what to what?

Comment: Yes, the upper are a problems for themselves to be expressed in closed form. $N\rightarrow\infty$ and $n\rightarrow?$.

Comment: Do you have access to Maple? If so, I'll post the code as an answer. Then you can fool with the data.

Comment: No thats the reason I have asked for some.

Comment: Do you have access to _any_ programing language? The code is short and simple.

Comment: gfortran I suppose, or bash.

Comment: I'll post the Maple code. It should be easy to convert to whatever language you have available.

Comment: You can try as an answer, and please give $f(n,3)$.

Comment: Is $f(n,3)=$ https://oeis.org/A026930 correct?

Comment: It doesn't match my results (to be posted soon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @quasi's answer implies, the question can be obviously reformulated to: "What is the number $m$ of partitions of $n$ into $N$ distinct parts?".

In that form for $N = 2, 3$ partial sequences are contained e.g. in the OEIS sequences [for $N=2$](https://oeis.org/A034150) and [$N$=3](https://oeis.org/A034092) and, the latter also contains a concise formulation in terms of a generating function:

For each $N$ the sequences are formed by the coefficients of the terms $t^N$ in the product
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1+t q^i)$$

which is identical to $(-t;q)_\infty$ in q-Pochhammer symbol notation
(in Mathematica code you can get partial sequences up to size $N$ with `CoefficientList[Coefficient[Product[1+t*x^i, {i,N}], t^N], x]`, by setting the appropriate value of $N$, sequence members larger than $N$ are incorrect for that purpose due to the truncation of the generating product.)

As @quasi pointed out a closed form for $N=2$, $s_N = 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,\dots = ({\lfloor}\frac{N-1}{2}{\rfloor})_N $ is obvious. For $N>2$ no closed form seems to be known. In Analogy to the case for the closely related partition number of n it can be conjectured that at least a recursive expression and maybe a convergent approximation exists.

Answer (score 0):

For positive integers $n,k$ with $k \le n$, let  $f(n,k)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts.

Then $f(n,k) = g(n,k,1)$, where $g(n,k,m)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts such that the smallest part is greater than or equal to $m$.

The values of $g$ can be computed recursively.

Here's a Maple implementation . . .

[image]

Comment: Your $f(n,k)$ is not my $m$, the question is about. Or at least its very opaque how they might be connected.

Comment: Why not? How is it different? You want to count the number of sets of $k$ positive integers whose sum is $n$. Right?

Comment: You are starting with your own definition which differs from the OP ones and do not show how they are connected.

Comment: As I see it, they're obviously the same.

Comment: Can you give a numerical example, showing how they're different?

Comment: I think you have to show the equivalency of the definitions in order that this can be regarded as a proper answer. It is not obvious. Counterexamples would only cover the case that your answer is wrong, which is not clear, yet.

Comment: Your sums _are_ partitions of $n$. And there are exactly $k$ summands (I'm using $k$ instead of $N$ for notational convenience). So each of your $m$ sums is a partition of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts.

Comment: Thinking about it it may be the same. Still some comment on that is missing. You could add "which is a reformulation of OPs question", or the like.

Comment: Aren't you the OP?

Comment: Yes I am, why ?

Comment: So if you now understand the obvious equivalence, what's the issue?

Comment: I think the sense of MSE is that it should be Q-A type and as clearly as possible. If someone searches for my question and finds an answer to an uncommented reformulation of the question its not a clear situation.

Comment: I think that at the level of the question, the reformulation will be transparent to most readers. In any case. it _is_ commented, right here in the comment section.